# where to put the resource folder when manually installing program

Tags: software-installation, software-sources

I know that I can manually install a binary by placing it it in `/usr/local/bin` or some other folder in my `PATH` variable. I'm not sure how to go about applications that have a resource folder around them.

i.e: Many programs that come without an installer will have some folder around them that contains a bunch of stuff that the program needs to run properly. The install instructions will say something like "Download, unzip, enjoy!", which is works but is annoying for programs you will actually use.

Dropping the whole folder into the installation directory doesn't work since subfolders aren't explored. What is the 'proper' way to install these programs?

bonus question: Is there any way to automate the process?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is the exact software name? Without a software name this question is too broad.

Comment: Where you place "resource" folders entirely depends on where the software expects to find them.

Comment: Read `man hier`, the document the explains the Linux Filesystem Hieracy

Comment: @vanadium I was expecting something like that. So I'm guessing it's there's not real universal solution? I'm thinking of either creating a link through a batch script or just adding the extra folder to my path.

Comment: You have to install specific software the way it expects to be installed - yes, you have to read its installation instructions. No universal approach here, except conventions explained in the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy, which a developer follows or does not follow, although developers will normally not go too much out of line - their software would otherwise not be accepted by the community.